# Modify haystack query syntax?

Tags: django-haystack

Is it possible to modify or extend how haystack understands a query?

For example, I'm looking at integrating haystack with an OSQA-based site to get SO-style search -- a search where regular keywords search question/answer/comment text, **but** where syntax like "[tag]" is understood to be restricted to the question's `tags` field.  At some point we might want to add other goodies like "user:eternicode" and "score:0", but for now keywords and tags are the must-haves.

Unfortunately, it's not as simple as regexing the tags out of the query string and using that to filter on the `tags` field, because we want all the complexity of `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, and arbitrary grouping to apply.

Is this possible with haystack?  Better yet, has anyone done it before?

Comment: were you ever able to figure this one out?

Comment: No, we never could figure out how to customize haystack's internals.  What we ended up doing was preparsing the search query to extract tag and other custom queries, perform the auto_query with the remainder, and then apply the custom queries as extra filters on the auto_query results.  In order to do this, though, we had to simplify our requirements and drop the `OR` requirement, so all terms are only `AND`ed now -- that simplified a lot of things (for example, grouping is now unnecessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to customize how Haystack's `auto_query` works, so what we ended up doing was preparsing the search query to extract tag and other custom syntaxes, perform the auto_query with the leftovers, and then apply the custom syntaxes as extra filters on the auto_query results.

In order to do this, though, we had to simplify our requirements and drop the OR requirement, so all terms are only ANDed now -- that simplified a lot of things (for example, grouping is now unnecessary).